# How to save data

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to save data with Python and Json, Im trying to have it save like this

```
"UserID" {
"Code":12123
}
```

But I cannot get anywhere near this look or working order. Here is the code that is saving to the Json.

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data.append([str(ctx.author.id)]["Code"])


with open('data.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

How can I get it to save like my example above so I can be able to get the code via the userid when fetching the codes.

Comment: Edited, I forgot to put in that part.

Comment: can you provide an example of expected output and input?

Comment: Your expected data isn't valid JSON. Are you sure that's what you want it to look like? If  so, you'll need to write (and read) it some other custom way.